# Verificar qual p não possui texto

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como verificar qual `p` não possui valor de texto?

Tenho o seguinte código HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>bbbbbbbbbb</p>
    <p></p>
    <p>aaaaaac</p>
    <p></p>
    <p>uuuuuuuuuuu</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Se a tag `p` não possuir texto, adicione `display: none;` na mesma.

Comment: Cara mas um `<p></p>` já é "display:none" por natureza. A tag P vazia não ocupa espaço na página...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sem usar jQuery, em JavaScript puro, o método `querySelectorAll` aceita o seletor `:empty`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('p:empty');
```

Desta forma irá restringir o laço apenas aos elementos `<p>` vazios, em vez de percorrer TODOS os `<p>`, dispensando a verificação com `if`:

```
const els = document.querySelectorAll('p:empty');
els.forEach(x=>{ x.style.display = "none" });
```

---

**Só que existe um problema que é possível ocorrer:** caso a tag `<p>` possua apenas *espaços em branco* (espaços também são caracteres) o seletor `querySelectorAll('p:empty')` não irá selecionar. Exemplos:

```
1º. <p></p>  -> esta tag está vazia
2º. <p>      -> esta tag NÃO está vazia,
    </p>        possui espaços porque está sendo fechada em uma nova linha
```

O seletor `:empty` do jQuery funciona diferente e irá considerar ambos os exemplos acima "vazios"; já o do `querySelectorAll` apenas o 1º.

No caso de usar jQuery, basta usar o seletor `:empty` com `.hide()`:

```
$('p:empty').hide();
```

---

Caso haja a possibilidade mencionada acima, do `<p>` ser fechado numa outra linha, usando JavaScript puro, a resposta do Luiz Filipe é satisfatória usando o `if`, porém é necessário acrescentar a função `.trim()` para limpar os caracteres vazios:

```
const els = document.querySelectorAll('p');
els.forEach(el => {
  if (!el.textContent.trim()) {
    el.style.setProperty('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Caso você não queira usar jQuery, pode fazer assim:

```js
const els = document.querySelectorAll('p');

els.forEach(el => {
  if (! el.textContent) {
    el.style.setProperty('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>bbbbbbbbbb</p>
    <p></p>
    <p>aaaaaac</p>
    <p></p>
    <p>uuuuuuuuuuu</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Com jQuery:

```
$('p:empty').css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: Seu JS não irá funcionar se o `<p>` e o fechamento `</p>` estiverem em linhas diferentes. Uma quebra de linha no código gera caractere, logo a tag não estará vazia.

Comment: Solução: adicione um `.trim()`: `if (! el.textContent.trim()) {`

Comment: @sam perfeito, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Ficaria assim o trecho de código em JQuery:

```
$('p:empty').css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: `$('p:empty').hide();` tem o mesmo efeito e eu acho até mais elegante :)

Comment: Verdade, mais uma opção que atende a pergunta e ainda se escreve menos código :P